# MySQL Finding intersection where 2 entered dates intersect between a start_date and end_date

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, where-clause

I am trying to find if 2 entered dates have an intersection between a start date/time and end date/time.

Example in my database table "reservation" we have a row(s) with the following

start_date = `2022-02-28 09:00:00`
end_date = `2022-02-28 11:00:00`

I would like to build a query where i can select this row when i pass in the following inputs

start date = `2022-02-28 08:30:00`
end date = `2022-02-28 12:30:00`

Now this filter should select any rows where the date/time intersect with it. I built the below query, however,  this does not select the intersection that i want. Is there anything i can do to adjust the below query? This query works for the most part (when dates are truly inside the start/end date) but does not do any intersection like this. This query works for the most part but just not this scenario.

```
SELECT
    rp.product_id
FROM
    reservation r
    INNER JOIN reservation_product AS rp ON r.reservation_id = rp.reservation_id
WHERE
    (
        '2022-02-28 08:30:00' BETWEEN r.start_date
        AND r.end_date
    )
    OR (
        '2022-02-28 12:30:00' BETWEEN r.start_date
        AND r.end_date
    )
```

Example Data - The below inputs should select that row in the square.

start date = `2022-02-28 08:30:00`
end date = `2022-02-28 12:30:00`

[image]

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and exepct result?

Comment: I think `2022-02-28T09:00:00-05:00` that isn't a valid `DateTime`

Comment: @D-Shih I added example and updated the datetime to reflect correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find intersections if `start_date` is less than the max of the 2 dates and `end_date` is greater than the min of the 2 dates:

```
WHERE r.end_date >= '2022-02-28 08:30:00'
  AND r.start_date <= '2022-02-28 12:30:00'
```

Comment: This is working well, I think I was over complicating this. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

The intervals A and B intersection condition is `A.start<=B.End AND B.start <= A.End`

```
.. 
WHERE
    (
        '2022-02-28 08:30:00' < r.end_date
    )
    AND (
        '2022-02-28 12:30:00' > r.start_date
    )
```